# plotting the count of x-value in one col in df in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am in a bit of a struggle and I can't find a solution (it should be very simple)
my Code is this

```
df
Ch1  V1  V2  ID
A    a1  a2  1
B    b1  b2  2
C    a1  b2  1
D    d1  d2  3
...
```

in total we have values ranging from 1 to 9. 
I simply want to plot how often 1(,2,3,...,9) occurs in this data frame. My code is this

```
ggplot(df,aes(ID))+   #because I read that leaving y value makes ggplot count the occurences which is T
  geom_bar()+
```

This works but unfortunately I get this as a result [image]
I want all values to be displayed though. 
I tried to modify this with `scale_x_continuous`
but it didn't work (made the whole x-axis go away and display only 1)

I know I can also create a `table = table(df)`

But I want to find a universal solution. Because later I want to be able to apply this while making several bars per x-axis value with dependency on V1 or V2 ...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Convert ID to a factor then plot.

Comment: Perfect worked - easy as that. I actually did factor(ID).

Comment: If I would like to plot  V1 with different bars depending on how often ID-value occurs for V1-value, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: I am trying this
`ggplot(data=df%>% gather(Variable, ID, -V1),
       aes(x = factor(reorder(V1,-ID)),  fill = Variable))`

Comment: Just add `fill = V1` to the aesthetic.  You shouldn't need to reshape your data.  `ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, fill = V1)) + geom_bar()`  The bars are stacked by default - if you don't want this use `geom_bar(position = "dodge")`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OP, the intention is to create

> several bars per x-axis value with dependency on V1 or V2

This can be solved either by using `fill = V1` and `position = "dodge"` as already suggested [H 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889005/plotting-the-count-of-x-value-in-one-col-in-df-in-r#comment105907097_59889005) or by facetting. Both approaches have their merits depending on the aspect the OP wants to focus on.

Note that in all variants `ID` is turned into a discrete variable (using `factor()`) and by overriding the default axis title to solve the issue with labeling the x-axis.

#### Dogded position

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x = factor(ID), fill = V1) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  xlab("ID")
```

[image]

This is good if the focus is on comparing the differences between `V1` within each `ID` value.

#### Facets

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x = factor(ID), fill = V1) +
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("ID") +
  facet_wrap(~ V1, nrow = 1L)
```

[image]

Here, the focus is on comparing the distribution of `ID` counts within each `V1`.

Colouring the bars in addition to faceting is redundant (but I find it aesthetically more pleasing as compared to all-black bars).

#### Data

As there were no reproducible data supplied in the question, I have tried to simulate the data by

```
nr <- 1000L
set.seed(123L) # required to reproduce the data
df <- data.frame(Ch1 = sample(LETTERS[1:4], nr, TRUE),
                 V1 = paste0(sample(letters[1:4], nr, TRUE), "1"),
                 V2 = paste0(sample(letters[1:4], nr, TRUE), "2"),
                 ID = pmin(1L + rgeom(nr, 0.3), 9L)
)
```

"Raw" plot for comparison with OP's chart

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + 
  aes(x = ID) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]